# Pokeapi and getting resource_uri

Tags: arrays, json, dictionary, afnetworking

So Im using AFNetworking and the pokeapi to get the list of pokemon. I can get the tableview to load with the title being the name of the pokemon. But I want the subtitle to be the type. So I set the base to be `#define pokeApiBaseURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://pokeapi.co/"]`

Here is what my request looks like. I made an array which gives me the next half of the url I need to parse and get the type and all the rest of the pokemon's info. But I can't seem to figure out how to make the baseURL and the resource_uri to create a new url for me to parse.

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@api/v1/pokedex/1/", pokeApiBaseURL];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


    self.pokemonArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"pokemon"];
    self.pokemonDetailArray = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"pokemon"]valueForKey:@"resource_uri"];




   // NSLog(@"\n%@",detailString);

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Request Failed: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);

}];

[operation start];
```

Here is where I'm adding it to the cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdenifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdenifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


NSDictionary *pokemonDictionary = [self.pokemonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSDictionary *pokemonDetailDictionary = [self.pokemonDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
[cell.textLabel sizeToFit];
cell.textLabel.text = [pokemonDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"PLACEHOLDER"; //WANT THE TYPE TO GO HERE!

return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### EDIT

I had some free time this morning due to a client not getting back to me, and whipped this up : https://github.com/AlexTrott/PokeAPI : far from perfect, this is just showing you how to store the data locally on first load, if you have any questions let me know.

---

---

Heres how to get the URLs and information you want *[(I used AFHTTPSessionManager as the method you use is about to be deprecated in AFN3](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-3.0-Migration-Guide)*) :

```
-(void)loadData {
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager GET:@"http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokedex/1/" parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
        pokemonArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"pokemon"];
        pokemonDetailArray = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"pokemon"]valueForKey:@"resource_uri"];
        [self loop];
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}

-(void)loop {
    for (int i = 0; i < [pokemonArray count]; i++) {
        [self loadMore:i];
    }
}

-(void)loadMore:(int)pokemonID {
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", pokeApiBaseURL, [pokemonDetailArray objectAtIndex:pokemonID]];
    NSLog(@"URL = %@", url);
    NSLog(@"Loop Number = %d", pokemonID);
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"response = %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

I think you need to rethink how to approach this, I just checked out the poke api, and to do what you want you have to make 779 calls, 1 which is the pokedex call, and the other which is the 778 pokemon.

You can lower this by one, by removing the pokedex request, and just forming an array based on the data, but then you are doing 778 request, which is crazy in my opinion, I think you need to work out how you want to display the data, and if you wouldn't be better off doing a first time load, or compiling the data your self and having it locally, as 778 request is crazy.

If you do have to do that many request make sure it'd only once and the first time they load the app or something, and then store in CD or realm or something.

For a very quick and dirty example to get your data into one NSMutableArray which is sorted take a look at this, I wouldn't do it like this, I'd batch it or store locally on load, but it should give you a better idea of what you want to do.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>

@interface ViewController () {
    NSString *pokeApiBaseURL;
    NSMutableArray *pokedex;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateTable) name:@"orginalDone" object:nil];
    pokeApiBaseURL = @"http://pokeapi.co/";
    pokedex = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < 151; i++) {
        [self loadData:i];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


-(void)loadData:(int)pokemonID {
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/%d/", pokemonID];
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
        [self addPokemon:responseObject];
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}

-(void)addPokemon:(id)pokemonObject {
    NSMutableDictionary *pokemonData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [pokemonData setObject:pokemonObject[@"pkdx_id"] forKey:@"pkmnID"];
    [pokemonData setObject:pokemonObject[@"name"] forKey:@"pokemonName"];
    NSMutableArray *types = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < [pokemonObject[@"types"] count]; i++) {
        [types addObject:pokemonObject[@"types"][i][@"name"]];
    }
    [pokemonData setObject:types forKey:@"types"];
    [pokedex addObject:pokemonData];
    NSLog(@"count = %lu", (unsigned long)[pokedex count]);
    if ([pokedex count] == 150) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"orginalDone" object:nil];
    }
}

-(void)updateTable {
    NSLog(@"Unsorted = %@", pokedex);
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"pkmnID" ascending:YES];
    [pokedex sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    NSLog(@"Sorted = %@", pokedex);
}

@end
```

Comment: Wow thank you! Ive never used AFN and my knowledge is sub par at best. Just wanted to try something in my spare time. Thank you again!

Comment: It's alright, I think you just choose a bad example api to use, something like the public twitter one would of been great as it has multiple values, and images, so would be good practice handling the data

Comment: Ill give the twitter one a go too! Im going to try and take your pokeapi you made and use a storyboard so I can rearrange the labels in the cells. Its a huge help being able to see how all of that is handled in yours.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably looking for this method to combine a resource with the base:

```
+ (instancetype)URLWithString:(NSString *)URLString
            relativeToURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/URLWithString:relativeToURL: